# mock django.core.mail.send_mail in another function

Tags: python, django

I want to mock django's `send_mail()` so that it throws an Exception. My approach is as below, but mails are still being sent, and no Exceptions being thrown. It works if I call `send_mail()` directly within the context manager, but not if I call a function that imports and then uses `send_mail()`

```py
# test.py

import handle_alerts
from unittest import mock

class MailTest(TestCase):
  def test_handle_alerts(self):
     with mock.patch("django.core.mail.send_mail") as mocked_mail:
        mocked_mail.side_effect = Exception("OH NOES")

        handle_alerts()  # ends up using send_mail
```

```py
# handle_alerts.py

from django.core.mail import send_mail

def handle_alerts():
  send_mail(....)  # valid call goes here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mock function use, not function declaration.

```
class MailTest(TestCase):
    def test_handle_alerts(self):
        with mock.patch("handle_alerts.send_mail") as mocked_mail:
            mocked_mail.side_effect = Exception("OH NOES")

            handle_alerts()
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to work: no module called handle_alerts.

Comment: That's because you need to point patch to correct module, I have no idea what your project looks like so it was just example. If you would have app named 'users' where you have file named utils.py in which you have function handle_alerts full path would be 'users.utils.send_mail'

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is struggling with this like I was, it is possible that you don't need to mock it (source: [Django testing email service tools documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/tools/#email-services)):

> Django’s test runner automatically redirects all Django-sent email to a dummy outbox. This lets you test every aspect of sending email – from the number of messages sent to the contents of each message – without actually sending the messages.

So we can test if the email was sent like this:

```
self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1)
```

And also test other aspects of the mail (like the subject, body etc.):

```
self.assertEqual(sended_mail.subject, "Your subject...")
self.assertEqual(sended_mail.recipients(), [your recipients])
self.assertEqual(sended_mail.from_email, your_from_email)
```

If an exception is being thrown and we want to test it, a good approach is to set the data to force the email to throw an exception. If it is thrown in the actual code it will be in the test. However, if you just want to test how some function acts when the email throws an exception mocking the "wrapper" function that sends the email, a good approach is mentioned by @Ptomasz on Stack Overflow here:
[mock django.core.mail.send_mail in another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70987886/mock-django-core-mail-send-mail-in-another-function#comment125491966_70988134)